# Error when issuing BACKUP CERTIFICATE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, certificate

I am creating a certificate in one of my databases, which works without a problem. However, when I try to back up that certificate so that I can port it over to another database I receive the following error message:

```
An error occurred during decryption.
```

Here's my backup statement:

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE test_certs TO FILE = 'C:\test_certs.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'C:\test_certs.pvk',
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SomePassw0rd',
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SomeOtherPassw0rd')
```

Just to be safe, I've checked that the server has a C:\ drive with:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'DIR C:\'
```

I also confirmed that I could write to the location with:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo test > C:\test.txt'
```

So, unless the security used by BACKUP CERTIFICATE is different than that for xp_cmdshell (which is entirely possible), it's not an issue with writing to the disk.

Google turned up only a few results and none of them seemed to address this problem. Has anyone else seen this before? Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh... apparently the `DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD` (but not the `ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD`) must match the `ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD` of the `CREATE CERTIFICATE` command. I'll leave this here in case anyone else in the future has the same brain hiccup that I just did.